# Problems building android project with AAPT

Tags: android, xml, aapt

I'm attempting to build an android project's data without using gradle for educational, portability and efficiency reasons (both in running the build and setting it up). My project doesn't require the heavyweight build processes in gradle as it's 99% a C++ project built with make. I also wish to understand the underlying processes better and I find gradle hides these.

I'm using AAPT (should I be using AAPT2?) and need to include an existing library's resources. I've learned that I need to use '-S' for these and I've been experimenting with the ordering of those parameters - each order gives different errors.
My batch file (I'm working on Windows ATM) currently looks like this:

```
     echo off
set PROJ_DIR=%cd%
set BUILDTOOLSDIR=%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools\32.0.0
echo PROJ_DIR is %PROJ_DIR%
echo BUILD_TOOLS_DIR is %BUILDTOOLSDIR%
echo on
%BUILDTOOLSDIR%\aapt.exe package --non-constant-id -m -f ^
    -M %PROJ_DIR%\AndroidManifest.xml ^
    -I %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platforms\android-32\android.jar ^
    -P %PROJ_DIR%\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar ^
    -S C:\prog\libs\android\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\
    -S %PROJ_DIR%\res ^
    -J %PROJ_DIR%\src ^
    --generate-dependencies ^
    --auto-add-overlay
```

And I'm getting the following errors:

```
    android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'roundIcon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher_round').
android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
```

Those resources appear to exist, although I'm not sure how AAPT selects between the various resolution and shape variants I have. My 'res' directory looks like this:

```
    drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-v24
layout
mipmap-anydpi-v26
mipmap-hdpi
mipmap-mdpi
mipmap-xhdpi
mipmap-xxhdpi
mipmap-xxxhdpi
values
```

If I swap the order of the '-S' directories (I gather one of them is considered 'primary' and others 'overlays'), I get the following errors:

```
    \res\values\styles.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
\res\values\styles.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
\res\values\styles.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
```

However, all of those colour definitions are present in '\res\values\color.xml'
These errors caused me to swap the -S directories around to an order I thought was probably incorrect in the first place, which removed the colour errors but produced the icon errors.

My question is why are these linking errors occurring when the files all appear to be in place? Are there any more general tips for hand-coding calls to AAPT (or AAPT2) or obvious mistakes I'm making in my AAPT call?

Answer (score 0):

```
%BUILDTOOLSDIR%\aapt.exe package -f ^
-M %PROJ_DIR%\AndroidManifest.xml ^
-S %PROJ_DIR%\res ^
-S C:\prog\libs\android\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\ ^
-I %ANDROID_CP% ^
-I %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platforms\android-32\android.jar ^
-S %PROJ_DIR%\res ^
-J %PROJ_DIR%\src ^
-F %APK_BASENAME%.apk.unaligned ^
--generate-dependencies ^
--auto-add-overlay
```

In the end, this worked and I removed references to the colour themes as I wasn't using them anyway. APK still doesn't run correctly (cannot find a class that is clearly right there) but it's dalvikified, aligned, signed and on the device.